# Get access to methods in child interface when using Spring autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface A:

```
public interface Parent {
    method1()
}
```

And an interface B:

```
public interface Child extends Parent{
    method2()
}
```

Of course there is a class that implements interface B:

```
public class implements B{
@Override
method1(){
}

@override
method2(){
}
}
```

Now in a concrete class X, I use Spring autowiring to inject the interface "Parent":

```
public class X{

@Autowired
Parent parentImpl;

someMethod(){
}

)
```

But when I use the instance parentImpl, I only get access to method1
How can I get access to method2 in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: youo can do something like this.

`((Child)parentImpl).method2();`

But its not advisable

Answer (score 0):

If you inject the interface `Parent`, there's no way to access method2() because it is only known in interface `Child` and not in `Parent`.

But if you inject a variable of interface `Child` in class `X`, then method2() would be accessible.

It is not a problem of Spring or Autowiring but of interfaces and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Field parentImpl has type Parent, so you can invoke only Parent's methods.
If you want to be able to invoke Child's methods you should @Autowired Child interface

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Spring question but Java question.
If you know that your concrete class can be of the sub interface you can cast it:

```
((Child)impl).method2();
```

You should check that your impl class is of the sub interface

```
if (impl instance of Child) {
    ((Child)impl).method2();
}
```

However, I don't think it is a good practice, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore Spring and Autowiring, you will have the same problem.

```
public class X {

    private Parent parentImpl; //this is declared as a Parent. 

    public void someMethod() {
        //This will see parentImpl as type Parent 
        //because that is how it is declared in this class.
    }

)
```

If you want to be able to see `parentImpl` as a Child type, then it should be declared as such.